# Post to user wall on facebook from CodeIgniter

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

This question was asked already, but the accepted answer is not helpful as the poster seems to have figured it out themself and left out how they got the access token.

[Posting on Facebook wall from Codeigniter app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336698/posting-on-facebook-wall-from-codeigniter-app)

Anyhow, it seems that I can redirect to the login url and log in , but its not finding the auth token.  Throwing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user. thrown in
>   /home/howekevin/biologicalfinder.com/dev/application/libraries/base_facebook.php
>   on line 1040

Also, if you use the example on the SDK and `var_dump $user`, I'm getting `int 0` even after I'm logged in. I notice it's using a lot of `$GET` array stuff, and CodeIgniter doesn't jive with that. Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, so you found Elliot's broken code.  Give my oauth library a spin:

http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-oauth/versions/HEAD/show

Or Phil Sturgeon's:

http://getsparks.org/packages/oauth2/versions/HEAD/show

Our code should actually work ; )

Mind you mine and Phil's libraries only handle auth, but seems that's what you're having trouble with at the moment (and it's the hardest part).  Check out the Facebook developer docs for the rest (if you can make a POST request, you can do this).

Comment: update: I am now able to read account data, but I can't write.

Comment: Check out the "Publishing" section of this page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Would you know if a bad Curl request would generate this error:  string(77) "{"error":{"message":"Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}"

Comment: Check your app settings and make sure they match up with what's in your curl request.

Comment: finally got it working.  I had been trying to use the first library you provided up there.  When I switched to the sturgeon one for some reason the token I was getting back changed from 195 characters to 97 characters and started working.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Would you mind sending me the response from both?  calvinfroedge[at]gmail.com  Would like to take a look at that.

Comment: ok, I will do it before the end of my day.  Im kind of up against a deadline right now, but i will definitely.

Comment: what do you mean by response?  just the result or the getauth?